# Python PIL keeping last image in memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

In my code I am looping through a csv file, and for every line, an image is assigned based on one of the values.Like so:

```
if 'V,S,M' in s.com:
    compic = Image.open('Com-VSM.png')
elif "V,S" in s.com:
    compic = Image.open('Com-VS.png')
elif "V,M" in s.com:
    compic = Image.open('Com-VM.png')
elif "S,M" in s.com:
    compic = Image.open('Com-SM.png')
elif "V" in s.com:
    compic = Image.open('Com-V.png')
elif "S" in s.com:
    compic = Image.open('Com-S.png')
elif "M" in s.com:
    compic = Image.open('Com-M.png')
```

However, I notice that on occasion python holds onto the image used in the last loop, so if List[1] used 'Com-M.png' and List[2] uses 'Com-S.png' the result is that when the image is made, List[2] will have 'Com-S.png' superimposed over 'Com-M.png' any guesses as to how to fix this?

Full loop (The garbage collector stuff was an attempt to severely purge memory):

```
for s in L:
    scho = 0

    if 'Necromancy' in s.school:
        scho = necromancy
    elif 'Abjuration' in s.school:
        scho = abjuration
    elif 'Conjuration' in s.school:
        scho = conjuration
    elif 'Divination' in s.school:
        scho = divination
    elif 'Evocation' in s.school:
        scho = evocation
    elif 'Enchantment' in s.school:
        scho = enchantment
    elif 'Illusion' in s.school:
        scho = illusion
    elif 'Transmutation' in s.school:
        scho = transmutation
    else:
        scho = abjuration

    compic = 0
    font = ImageFont.truetype("Livingst.ttf", 48)


    #region Components
    if 'V,S,M' in s.com:
        compic = Image.open('Com-VSM.png')
    elif "V,S" in s.com:
        compic = Image.open('Com-VS.png')
    elif "V,M" in s.com:
        compic = Image.open('Com-VM.png')
    elif "S,M" in s.com:
        compic = Image.open('Com-SM.png')
    elif "V" in s.com:
        compic = Image.open('Com-V.png')
    elif "S" in s.com:
        compic = Image.open('Com-S.png')
    elif "M" in s.com:
        compic = Image.open('Com-M.png')
    else:
        compic = Image.open('Com-VSM.png')
    #endregion

    image_copy = scho.image
    image_copy.paste(compic, scho.point5, compic)
    imgpath = 's.name + '.png'
    image_copy.save(imgpath)
    del compic
    gc.collect()
```

Comment: If you re-assign a name like `compic` in a loop, it will *always* be what its last value was when you start again at the top of the loop. My suspicion is that it *doesn't* get assigned in your `if/elif` block if a particular condition is met, and that's what's throwing you off. Throw an `else` in there and see if there's a corner case you didn't expect. Otherwise, you should probably paste more of your code, at least the part containing the `for` loop.

Comment: @LukasGraf more code has been posted.

Comment: Please, can you reindent your code. It’s not clear what is in the loop and what is not.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE It's been reindented. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

In your `if ... elif ...` you forget a `else` statement. So you *compic* variable is not set on every loop if no condition is satisfied.

All you need is to add an `else` statement to check all cases.

If you don’t have one, the best practice is to raise `NotImplementedError`, for instance:

```
if 'V,S,M' in s.com:
    compic = Image.open('Com-VSM.png')
elif "V,S" in s.com:
    compic = Image.open('Com-VS.png')
elif "V,M" in s.com:
    compic = Image.open('Com-VM.png')
elif "S,M" in s.com:
    compic = Image.open('Com-SM.png')
elif "V" in s.com:
    compic = Image.open('Com-V.png')
elif "S" in s.com:
    compic = Image.open('Com-S.png')
elif "M" in s.com:
    compic = Image.open('Com-M.png')
else:
    raise NotImplementedError(s.com)
```

That way it is easier to find missing cases